# Laravel welcome.blade page displays code

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

A few days ago I posted here a question about the fact that I had a project only displaying code on the browser, even though I had helpful answers I couldn't reach the needed solution, so I took a break.

Today, after reinstalling composer and artisian (They were having errors before, but now they are working properly, I supose), I decided to create a new empty project. It worked all fine, the project was crafted, I updated the composer to make sure it was all good, but when I opened the welcome.blade.php view, which usually shows the default laravel page, It was displaying code from the body. I checked the documentation from laravel and It seems that it has all the necessary extensions from php.

[Here's an image of what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNblc.png) (cant upload here because, reputation)

Is it possible that I missed the instalation of some extension?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked in chrome ?

Comment: No, I don't have chrome installed in this computer, but I tried on Internet Explorer and was displaying the same error

Comment: you are not suppose to expose blade files. Your apache web root should point to public folder of laravel

Comment: rahul_m what is the relation of this issue with chrome ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ehfgw4 like this?

Comment: Yes, Create a virtual host and point it to the public folder of your app.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ehfkgc I created a vhost, runned the apache file to check for erros, but it still displays the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going directly to a blade file, your browser simply interprets this as HTML as it is not compiled.

In your controller you want to return the view by using

```
view('view.name')
```

You are coming across expected behaviour since the view hasn't been compiled yet and PHP won't understand @ tags

Comment: I was just typing the same :)

Comment: Laravel uses blade to render the views but if you access it directly it simply does not get rendered and so displays the blade code in your html

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ehfhx1 You are saying that in the Controller.php there should be this line of code?
I don't think I ever added this kind of line to the project and it was able to work properly previously

Comment: The explanation you gave for the problem makes sense to me but I still have that problem. Maybe I did something wrong, are you sure I only have to write 
view('welcome.blade.php') ?

Comment: Well you have to write it in the controller method that is being called. The only reason I can think of it working previously for you is that you never had any blade syntax in the templates.

Laravel gets the view specified then compiles it into native PHP, Blade views should never be publicly accessible, hence by default they are under `resources/views` rather than `public/views`.

Maybe you are mis understanding how Laravel works, in this case I would recommend checking their documentation and underdstanding the request life cycle.

Comment: Ok, I'll focus on that, thanks for the helpful comment!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the filename of you blade is xxxxx.blade.php
I copied an old blade and quickly renamed and forgot the blade part.
I know this is old, but I google seached to here today.